# Redirecting a url with a path to another website

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using AWS how would I go about changing a url like so: "www.mywebsite.com/path/data" to another website?

I managed to do a url redirect with my domain "www.mwebsite.com" but having issue with the path part.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your Website hosted? And what web server is it using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS support pointed a simpler solution. It's basically the same idea proposed by @Vivek M. Chawla, with a more simple implementation.

AWS S3:

1. Create a Bucket named with your full domain, like `aws.example.com`
2. On the bucket properties, select `Redirect all requests to another host name` and enter your URL:
   `https://myaccount.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/`

AWS Route53:

1. Create a record set type A. Change Alias to `Yes`. Click on `Alias
   Target` field and select the S3 bucket you created in the previous
   step.

Reference: [How to redirect domains using Amazon Web Services](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/aws-domain-redirection/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Would you now how I can achieve this using a GoDaddy account? I currently host my domain in GoDaddy and would like the achieve the same result from there.

Comment: @Pashtidot Check this out https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120